# How to convert a rails Active Records object to to key:name JSON pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

How to convert a rails **Active Records** object's id:name hash object  to JSON format object

```
Users.select("id,name").all
```

**To json**

```
{1:manish,2:john,3:paulo}
```

I want the output json like above,So I can use that in my JavaScript.

Please help me regarding this!

Comment: Please note, I DON'T want => {1:manish},{2:john},{3:paulo}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Hash[Users.select("id,name").all.map{|u| [u.id, u.name]}].to_json
```